# Toolbar Spinner doesn't show a text

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-toolbar

**UPDATED**
I need to make a `Spinner` in the `Toolbar`. Below `AppBarLayout` xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/toolbarSpinner"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/path"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="snap"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

App style:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.SolidStatusBar" parent="AppTheme" />

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/black_30</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Dropdown title xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_spinner_triangle"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_spinner_triangle"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="4dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Dropdown item:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:textColor="#ff333333"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here current result (`Spinner` doesn't show a text). What do I doing wrong?
[image: Non-dropdown]
[image: Dropdown]

Adapter

```
public class ToolbarSpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static final String TAG = ToolbarSpinnerAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    private List<Item> mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ToolbarSpinnerAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public void clear() {
        mItems.clear();
    }

    public void add(final Item item) {
        mItems.add(item);
    }

    public void addAll(List<Item> items) {
        mItems.addAll(items);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(final int position) {
        return mItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(final int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (view == null || !view.getTag().toString().equals("DROPDOWN")) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.toolbar_si_dropdown, parent, false);
            view.setTag("DROPDOWN");
        }

        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        textView.setText(getTitle(position));

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (view == null || !view.getTag().toString().equals("NON_DROPDOWN")) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.toolbar_si, parent, false);
            view.setTag("NON_DROPDOWN");
        }

        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        textView.setText("Test");
        return view;
    }

    private String getTitle(final int position) {
        return position >= 0 && position < mItems.size() ? mItems.get(position).mTitle : "";
    }

    public static final class Item {
        private String mTitle;
        private Object mTag;

        public Item(final String title) {
            this.mTitle = title;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return mTitle;
        }

        public Item setTitle(final String title) {
            mTitle = title;
            return this;
        }

        @Nullable
        public Object getTag() {
            return mTag;
        }

        public Item setTag(@Nullable Object tag) {
            mTag = tag;
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

**ADDED**
I understood my bug. Method `public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)` is not called in the adapter (only for dropdown views). What could be behind the magic? (I checked it in the LogCat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to set the theme for you `Spinner`, as it should inherit its attributes from the theme overlay you specified in your `Toolbar`. But, I don't think it inherits the popup theme you specified, so you should set that in your `Spinner` as well.  Also, there is no need for an extra `LinearLayout` to wrap your `Spinner`. You can either use the `Spinner` as the root object in your xml:

```
<Spinner xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
```

Or place it directly in your `Toolbar`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed" app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Lastly, make sure your are not displaying the title in your `Toolbar`:

```
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thanks! The result is better but the spinner text doesn't show all same (only triangle shows)

Comment: I posted my adapter code. I tried all but I cannot understand where is bug.

Answer (score 0):

I found this bug. The problem is `Spinner` view that will not work correctly if its adapter was empty at the creation moment. To fix this when we will add new items in the adapter we will should re-set the adapter again calling `spinner.setAdapter(adapter);`